# Laravel Nested Foreach loop from collection

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

I have the following collection:

Screenshot:
[image]
What I would like to do is return each state college across in 3 rows by state using a blade template. For example:

Massachusetts

college 1             college 2            college 3

Florida

college 1             college 2            college 3

college 4

...

I have tried many different suggested examples from other posts, but have not been able to find a solution.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Here is what I have tried:

     @foreach ($colleges as $college)
      @foreach($college as $state)
        <h1 style="center">{{ $state[0]['College']['state'] }}</h1>
      <ul class="nospace clear">
        <li class="one_quarter first">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $state[0]['College']['logo'])  }}" alt="{{ $state[0]['College']['college'] }}" />
          </a>
          <h3 class="center">{{ $state[0]['College']['college'] }}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Greg

Comment: Instead of showing what you actually tried, you decided to just ask others to write code for you. You probably should hire a developer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of your collection screenshot, it has the following structure:

```
[
  state
    college
    college

  state
    college
    college
    college

  ...
]
```

Therefore, if you `foreach` over the `$states` collection, taking the `$key` as the state name and the `$value` as that state's college collection, you can do the following:

```
@foreach ($states as $state => $colleges)
    <h1 style="center">{{ $state }}</h1>

    <ul class="nospace clear">
        @foreach ($colleges as $college)
            <li class="one_quarter first">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $college->logo) }}" alt="{{ $college->college }}" />
                </a>
                <h3 class="center">{{ $college->college }}</h3>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```